# How to use a popup menu that has buttons?

Tags: android, eclipse, popup

I'm writing a program for android, I want to use a popup Menu that has two buttons that When I click on each of them, they open another activity.How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View looks like this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.SOME_LAYOUT, false);
Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.BUTTON1_ID);
button1.setOnClickListener(...start new Activity); 
Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.BUTTON2_ID);
button2.setOnClickListener(...start new Activity);
```

Set this view as content :

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(getContext());
popup.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
popup.setContentView(view);
popup.setWidth(view.getWidth());
popup.setHeight(view.getHeight());
popup.setFocusable(true);
popup.showAsDropDown(PARENT_VIEW);
```

View is inflated layout wich has two buttons with set click listeners. Parent view is that will show this popup on click.

Good luck!